# Call a method in the Static void main

Tags: java, arrays, methods, static, void

Hy my method is this:

```
public static String[] getcontestants(String[] contestants) {
    int numcontestants = 8;
    String name[] = new String[numcontestants];
    for (int j = 0; j < numcontestants; j++) {
        Scanner ip = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter contestant's name");
        name[j] = ip.nextLine();
    }
    return name;
}
```

I would like to call this method in the static void main but I don't exactly know how to do it. Tell me if there's any mistake in this method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So tbh, I like Maarten Bodewes's answer better, but I think this might be a bit easier for you to understand.

Main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] contestants = getcontestants();
}
```

I edited Your function just a bit:

```
public static String[] getcontestants()
{
    int numcontestants=8;
    String name[] = new String[numcontestants];

    for(int j=0;j<numcontestants;j++){
        Scanner ip=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter contestant's name");
        name[j]=ip.nextLine();
    }
    return name;
}
```

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
MyClass.getcontestants(new String[] { "MS", "MR" });
```

where `MyClass` is the class that contains the method. You can leave out `MyClass.` if your `main` method is in the same `MyClass` class.

---

This is a direct answer to your question. If you look at the design of your class then [Hadeems answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50302600/589259) shows you that you don't need to pass the `String` array to the method; the scanner can be used locally.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create scanner object in this method (it will create as many objects as the loop goes which is not the standard way of coding & not efficient at all).

Declare `static Scanner ip = new.... ;`  outside the method within a class as global variable. (`static` - so that it's only one instance)

```
 class YourClassName{
     static Scanner ip = new....;
     public static void main(String [] args){
          //String[] inputStringArray = getcontestants( //new String (){"my", "text", "as", "string", "array"});
          // Why passing string array to the function where actually you are taking input from user
          // Better don't pass anything except length of the string array 
         String[] inputStringArray = getcontestants(contestanstCount);
     }
     public static String[] getcontestants(..){}
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the code. Try it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class AmadouQuestion {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] names = getcontestants(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(names[i]);
    }
}
public static String[] getcontestants(int numcontestants)
{
    Scanner ip=new Scanner(System.in);

     String[] names = new String[numcontestants];
     for(int j=0;j<numcontestants;j++){

         System.out.println("Enter contestant's name");
         names[j]=ip.nextLine();
    }
     ip.close();
   return names;
}
```

}

Comment: But the thing is that I don't want the program to print the names at the end